# Highcharts Export Server 0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data

Tags: highcharts

I'm exporting charts with our self-hosted highcharts export server (v2.0.16), but when running multiple charts (~15-30) in sequence, we're getting the error:

0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data

Sometimes it does work properly, but when we generate more charts, the likelihood of failure seems to increase.

I've also tried to increase the amount of workers to 10 and the timeoutThreshold to 60.000, but no luck so far.

Is there any fix or workaround to make sure we can export our charts properly?

When running the same chart requests at http://export.highcharts.com everything does work fine..

Update:
It seems that the worker (or my Azure VM) gets somewhat overworked, which is causing the error at some point. Given the timings.

```
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:07 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [notice] phantom worker 17 finished work ba79868327134e71b1d6723c1ea1c144 in 364 ms
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] got incoming HTTP request 5e475e1ef58742809b7f4f4b5d34e0a4
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] starting export
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] attempting to export from raw input
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom 17 - starting work
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [notice] phantom worker 17 finished work 5e475e1ef58742809b7f4f4b5d34e0a4 in 1025 ms
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] got incoming HTTP request 8e43b4cec4f24cecaeb0f5fb2e3f9bdf
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] starting export
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] attempting to export from raw input
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:09 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom 17 - starting work
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:11 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [notice] phantom worker 17 finished work 8e43b4cec4f24cecaeb0f5fb2e3f9bdf in 1341 ms
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] got incoming HTTP request 8fcb6f0fdd484aecbafd214e0a899d5d
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] starting export
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] attempting to export from raw input
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:12 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom 17 - starting work
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:16 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [notice] phantom worker 17 finished work 8fcb6f0fdd484aecbafd214e0a899d5d in 4173 ms
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] got incoming HTTP request dc34a21658634948985fa9d41eef89e7
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] starting export
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] attempting to export from raw input
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - received work, finding available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom - found available worker
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:17 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [verbose] phantom 17 - starting work
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:18 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [notice] phantom worker 17 - process was closed
Tue Nov 02 2021 08:17:18 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) [error] work dc34a21658634948985fa9d41eef89e7 could not be completed, sending: 0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data
```

Comment: At the this GitHub topic, you will find a possible workaround: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16530

Comment: We have a single self-hosted highcharts export. Is your suggestion that I don't do any async requests? Or that I use B64: true. I can obviously try that, but how is this topic related to the errors I'm getting?